# Algorithm to visit every node in a directed cyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, graph-traversal

As the title says, I have a graph that contains cycles and is directed. It's strongly connected so there's no danger of getting "stuck". Given a start node, I want to find the a path (ideally the shortest but that's not the thing I'm optimising for) that visits every node.

It's worth saying that many of the nodes in this graph are frequently connected both ways - i.e. it's *almost* undirected. I'm wondering if there's a modified DFS that might work well for this particular use case?

If not, should I be looking at the Held-Karp algortihm? The visit once and return to starting point restrictions don't apply for me.

Comment: Did you not succeed with a normal DFS or BFS?

Comment: @trincot Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't the cycles mess with both of the above? Plus I think the search space could become huge with BFS.

Comment: As long as you mark nodes as visited (and don't revisit them), there is no issue with either. Of course, the characteristic of BFS is that it uses more space. One flavor of BFS stores the whole path in each entry of the BFS queue: in case that is what you thought about, then don't do that. Just store a reference to the *previous* node on the path (linked list).

Comment: But with cycles/directed edges revisiting nodes would be necessary, no? On this graph for example https://computersciencewiki.org/index.php/File:Directed_graph.png, the only walk would be A,B,C,D,B,C,F. I can't see how the algorithm couldn't be guaranteed not to get stuck in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would probably be to choose a root arbitrarily and compute a BFS tree on G (i.e., paths from the root to each other vertex) and a BFS tree on the transpose of G (i.e., paths from each other vertex to the root). Then for each other vertex you can navigate to and from the root by alternating tree paths. There are various quick optimizations to this method.

Another possibility would be to use A* on the search space consisting of states current node × set of visited nodes, with heuristic equal to the number of nodes not visited yet. The worst-case running time is comparable to Held–Karp (which you could also apply after running Floyd–Warshall to form a complete unsymmetric distance matrix).

Comment: I like your first approach a lot. I guess the optimisation would be around the ordering in which you visit the vertexes in the "root and back" stage and also whether you need to travel all the way back to the root each time. Cheers!